# Sharepoint 2013 can I create and use form and workflow without infopath or sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

we have sharepoint 2013 - it does not allow infopath forms,  I have been tasked with creating simple travel approval request form and adding a workflow.
I have created a list with all the correct columns and I can save it as a template.
I can add items to the list and the form appears as I would like it to and the columns work correctly.   However I want to be able to forward the information as a form in the same way it appears when i am adding the information and route it to one of the approvers listed in choice column in my form.  I also want to store the forms in a list so when anyone looks at them they appear as a form and not a list.

The only workflows I have available are the approval - which seems to be for documents and also the three state workflow.

I am not a code person just been asked to undertake this task hence I am not able use sharepoint designer.   Is there anyway to achieve this please ?   I realise I am asking a lot however any links to websites/tutorials or anything that will help will be much appreciated

## Edit

I mean I want to store the information entered in a document which looks like the form. We cannot use InfoPath to create the forms since we are not running the correct version of sharepoint.

Comment: With Sharepoint Designer 2013, you have no code.
It's user friendly, you should to test.

Comment: "I also want to store the forms in a list so when anyone looks at them they appear as a form and not a list." What do you mean by this?

Comment: I have same question and found this open thread. I am looking for solution to customize workflow task form without InfoPath.